# Ubuntu 18.04 "Files" application automatic searching

Tags: nautilus

In Ubuntu 18.04, the "files" application behaves in - what to me anyway - is a very annoying way.

Scenario: I am viewing a directory containing some files. I want to access a particular file, lets say "readme.txt", so I hit the "r" key.

I would expect it highlight the first file beginning with the name "r". But no, instead it starts performing a global search. To me this is an illogical and counter-intuitive behavior: if I am in the context of a specific directory, why would you suddenly take that view away, and start doing a global search??

I prefer to use keyboard over mouse as much as possible, but the Files app in particular seems to be not very keyboard-friendly.

I looked in the settings, can't see an obvious way to change this behavior. Any suggestions?

Edit: There is an option to "only search in the current folder", but this doesn't work properly (often searches globally despite this settings), and it still has the annoying effect of changing the current view.

Comment: Yes you're right - at least it's not just me. It's weird that software that works well ends up being changed for the worse. This kind of nonsense seems to be happening a lot more lately too.